# Getting links to web services from a Google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, esri, arcgis-js-api

I often see many maps created in different API's and want to pick the best of them all to create my own mashup. Easy to do when debugging other API's like ESRI Javascript API I can get a rest end point in view source and use it in other GIS "viewers" and API's. But when I come up against a google map like this http://wildfire.alberta.ca/wildfire-status/wildfire-status-map.aspx

I cannot seem to debug and find a "service url" that I can say plug into another GIS client like ArcGIS Online. Is there such a thing as a underlying web accessible KML that I can snag - out of the above example?

Answer (score 1):

That URL is using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) to render KML.

```
// Add static regions KML
var regionsLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/apps/wildfirestatusmap/DataFiles/esrd_wma.kmz'
});
regionsLayer.setZIndex(1);
regionsLayer.setMap(map);

// Add dynamic markers
var wildfiresLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    //url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/wildfire-status/status-map-handler.ashx?type=map'
    url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/apps/wildfirestatusmap/status-map-handler.ashx?type=map'

});
wildfiresLayer.setZIndex(10);
wildfiresLayer.setMap(map);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  // Add static regions KML
  var regionsLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/apps/wildfirestatusmap/DataFiles/esrd_wma.kmz'
  });
  regionsLayer.setZIndex(1);
  regionsLayer.setMap(map);

  // Add dynamic markers
  var wildfiresLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    //url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/wildfire-status/status-map-handler.ashx?type=map'
    url: 'http://wildfire.alberta.ca/apps/wildfirestatusmap/status-map-handler.ashx?type=map'

  });
  wildfiresLayer.setZIndex(10);
  wildfiresLayer.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: This is great! I can access that KML in my other clients. However I am still a bit unclear how (where specifically) you got the path. So this is the link I neded http://wildfire.alberta.ca/apps/wildfirestatusmap/DataFiles/esrd_wma.kmz and when I view source on the original page that referenced above it is not there. So I presume it must be in the scripts or other filed residing with that htmls page - which is the page url that lists that .kmz layer